# How to access solution to linear system in PETSc?

Tags: linear-solver, petsc

I have just started with PETSc hence it might seem like a very stupid question but I couldn't find any answer in manual. 
After Calling KSPSolve, where can I access the soluition for my linear system?
Example  for a matrix:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 &-1 & 0\\
-1 &2&-1\\
0&-1&2
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\z
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\1
\end{array}\right)
$$

I want to get vector 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
3/4\\1/2\\1/4
\end{array}\right)
$$ 
back. 
The documentation for KSP Solve says `x - the solution (this may be the same vector as b, then b will be overwritten with answer)`

but I keep getting `x` vector as 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Is there something wrong in my understanding?

Comment: The solution to that (nonsingular) linear system is $[1, 1, 1]^T$. I don't understand why you want to get a vector that is not a solution.

Comment: Because I am that idiot who solved the equations wrong :| and assumed I am not able to get results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before** you solve the system in PETSc you store the matrix $A$ and RHS $b$.
The message from PETSc says, that **after** the system is solved, the solution might be overwritten into $b$, where originally the RHS was stored. That's what it means.

For the original system of equations:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 &-1 & 0\\
-1 &2&-1\\
0&-1&2
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\z
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\1
\end{array}\right)
$$
the correct solution is indeed (as pointed out by @JedBrown)
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\1
\end{array}\right)
$$

If you intend (for whatever good reason) to get 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
3/4\\1/2\\1/4
\end{array}\right)
$$
that only means that you have a typo in either your matrix or RHS. Assuming that your matrix is correct, you will get your desired solution for the following system (changed RHS slightly):
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 &-1 & 0\\
-1 &2&-1\\
0&-1&2
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\z
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\\color{red}{1/2}\\1
\end{array}\right)
$$